# Need help storing the previous element of a list (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on an assignment. I have a function called `gamaTipo` that converts the values of a tuple into a data type previously defined by my professor. 
The problem is: in order for `gamaTipo` to work, it needs to receive some preceding element. gamaTipo is defined like this: `gamaTipo :: Peca -> (Int,Int) -> Peca` where `Peca` is the data type defined by my professor.

What I need to do is to create a funcion that takes a list of tuples and converts it into `Peca` data type. The part that im strugling with is taking the preceding element of the list. i.e : let's say we have a list `[(1,2),(3,4)]` where the first element of the list `(1,2)` always corresponds to `Dirt Ramp` (data type defined by professor). I have to create a function `convert :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Peca]` where in order to calculate the element `(3,4)` i need to first translate `(1,2)` into `Peca`, and use it as the previous element to translate `(3,4)`

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    updateTuple :: [(Int,Int)] -> [Peca]
    updateTuple [] = []
    updateTuple ((x,y):xs) = let previous = Dirt Ramp
                                in (gamaTipo previous (x,y)): updateTuple xs
```

Although I get no error messages with this code, the expected output isn't correct. I'm also sorry if it's not easy to understand what I'm asking, English isn't my native tongue and it's hard to express my self. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What exactly are `Peca`, `Dirt`, and `Ramp`? Could you give us their definitions?

Comment: Actually, never mind. I think I can answer this without knowing their definitions.

Comment: if you eventually do need the definitions I can post them here aswell, but it's all in Portuguese, don't know if it would make a diference or not. I can try to translate it but I'm not sure it would be correct

Comment: No, I don’t need them — I actually just posted an answer.

Comment: BTW, well done on this question. You have been up-front about this being an assignment, explained your problem, showed what you have tried and asked a clear question with an answer that will be of use to other learners. Too often here we get "questions" that are merely cut-and-paste copies of a homework assignment, so this is a refreshing change.

Comment: FWIW the Haskell language library offers some ready-made recursion schemes. In your case, it would be the [scanl](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=scanl) function. Its type signature is: `scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]`. So the first argument would be your `gamaTipo` function, with type _a_ being (Int,Int) and type _b_ being Peca. You might want to compare your solution with the `scanl` source code in the library once you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your program needs to have a basic structure something like this:

```hs
updateTuple :: [(Int, Int)] -> [Peca]
updateTuple = go initialValue
  where
    go prev (xy:xys) =
        let next = getNextValue prev xy
        in prev : (go next xys)
    go prev [] = prev
```

Basically, what’s happening here is:

- `updateTuple` is defined in terms of a helper function `go`. (Note that ‘helper function’ isn’t standard terminology, it’s just what I’ve decided to call it).
- `go` has an extra argument, which is used to store the previous value.
- The implementation of `go` can then make use of the previous value.
- When `go` recurses, the recursive call can then pass the newly-calculated value as the new ‘previous value’.

This is a reasonably common pattern in Haskell: if a recursive function requires an extra argument, then a new function (often named `go`) can be defined which has that extra argument. Then the original function can be defined in terms of `go`.

Comment: So in this case all that the `go` helper function is doing is storing the previous element that I'm then going to use in `gamaTipo`?

Comment: @Ramux05 That’s exactly right. It’s actually quite simple when you express it like that, but I’ve found this pattern incredibly useful in my own code.